# quotient of SL_n

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, invariant-theory

Does anybody know why the quotient of $SL_n$ by its subgroup $Q_m:=\left\{\left(\begin{matrix}\xi&*&\cdots&*\\0&*&\cdots&*\\ \vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\ 0&*&\cdots&*\end{matrix}\right)\mid\xi\in\mu_m\right\}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^n/\mu_m$, where $\mu_m$ is the cyclic group of order $m$ and acts diagonally on $\mathbb{C}^n$?

Comment: The claim is not quite true, you have to remove the origin from $C^n$. A hint: First prove the claim for $m=1$ by considering the action of $SL_n$ on $C^n$ and the stabilizer of the vector $(1,0,...,0)^T$.